# Display other elements next to md-tab but below the tabs header

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm new to Angular Material and just found out about the md-tabs directive. I was wondering whether there is an easy way to insert a non-md-tab element to sit on the left (or right) of all md-tab elements, but below the tabs header.
Mockup of what I am looking for:

[image]

I guess I could just duplicate the markup and insert it into every single tab, but that doesn't seem to be a very practical solution. In any case, just adding a non-md-tab element as first child of md-tabs did not work.

Edit: another solution I thought about would be to manually load tab content based on which element is selected in the header area - I know how to do that - but then I'd lose the smooth transition animation between tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a directive for that, since you have to include it into your every tab's content. It would simply do the trick.

Or you can use only `md-tabs` without placing every tab's content into `md-tab`. Make use of `md-selected` of `md-tabs` and activate your html node visibilities in the right way. In this case you can have something on the left, since you'll define the layout.

Comment: your second suggestion is very much what I think would be best as well. the only thing i do not know is how to script the animations for the tab changes myself. but i guess that shouldn't be too hard

Comment: animations can be done easily too, no worries. Just maybe a little bit reading required to achieve it.